# Passing shared access signature token from SSIS parameter to PowerShell using SSIS Script Task (C#)

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, ssis, azure-storage

I need to run a PowerShell command to access my Azure storage account that requires some parameters that are stored within SSIS's package level and need to be passed from my SSIS packages using Script Task. Here is my C# code.

`Dts.Variables["User::upload_file"].Value = "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command \"C:\\\upload_file_to_blob.ps1\" -StorageAccountName \"" +
Dts.Variables["$Project::my_storageaccountname"].Value.ToString() + "\" -SasToken \"" +
Dts.Variables["$Project::my_sas"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString() + "\" -ContainerName \"" +
Dts.Variables["$Project::my_container"].Value.ToString() + "\" -BlobName \"" +
Dts.Variables["User::Blobname"].Value.ToString() + "\" -fileName \"" +
Dts.Variables["User::Filename"].Value.ToString() + "\"";`

I have tried debugging the code in so many different ways and mostly I treated the SAS Token as a string with "" or "//" however I couldn't get this working. The interesting thing is when I type the SAS Token into my PowerShell command directly it works just fine! I have a hypothesis that the problem is with my SAS Token that it contains % (percent) string and when passing the SAS Token from the SSIS parameter to PowerShell, there is a truncation or missing value.

Comment: You could try to write the SAS Token that is passed from SSIS parameter to a file via [Out-File cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and make sure if it is a valid SAS Token.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Fred Han - MSFT , I was able to solve the problem myself. Apparently the problem arose from the %% within the SAS Token as I have guessed. For passing SASToken as a string I used a single quotation **(')** instead of **(\")** Here is a piece of my code: **+ "\" -SasToken '" +
Dts.Variables["$Project::my_sas"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString() + "' -ContainerName \""** while everything else stays the same.